# How can I select nodes that don't contain links but which do contain specific text using xpath

Tags: xpath

Given the following HTML:

```
$content = 
'<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>During the interim there shall be nourishment supplied</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <p>During the <a href="#">interim</a> there shall be interim nourishment supplied</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <ul><li>During the interim there shall be nourishment supplied</li></ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>';
```

I want all the nodes containing the word "interim" but not if the word "interim" is part of a link element.

The nodes I would expect back are the first P node and the LI node only.

I've tried the following:

```
'//*/text()[not(a) and contains(.,"interim")]'
```

... but this still returns the A and also returns part of it's parent P node (the part after the A), neither of which are desired. You can see my attempt here: https://glot.io/snippets/ehp7hmmglm

Comment: Would you want the `p` element selected if `<p>interim <a href="#">link</a></p>` appeared in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the XPath expression `//*[not(self::a) and not(a) and text()[contains(.,"interim")]]` then you get all elements that do not contain an `a` element, are not `a` elements and contain a text node child containing that word.